# textblock forground color not changing with if statement

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written an if statement that I have already posted here once and now it is working correctly except for the color change I have. The different variables are being applied without a problem but the color change is not occurring. I'm assuming this is also something extremely simple that I am not catching it. any assistance would be great.  I can make the color change occur first but then the variables never show up in the textblock.

```
if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > 0)
{                        
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing.ToString(); }));
    callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
else if (e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable > 0)
{                        
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString(); }));
    callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}
else
{                        
    callsWaitingData.Text = "0";
    callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do the color change in the actions you pass to `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: it still doesn't work when I do that. same results

Comment: What do you mean by _"I can make the color change occur first but then the variables never show up in the textblock."_ - do you mean the color change does occur, but the text is not updated?

Comment: your original suggestion worked when attempted again. I think I had a compiling error the first time around or forgot a ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is the resolution. I tried this originally but for whatever reason it didn't work. when I attempted again it did. sorry for the trouble!

```
if (e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing > 0)
                    {
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.InQueueInRing.ToString();

                            callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); }));

                    }
                    else if (e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable > 0)
                    {                        
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();
                            callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);}));                        
                    }
                    else if(e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable == 0)
                    {
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { callsWaitingData.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();
                            callsWaitingData.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow); }));

                    }
```